# Simplistic level system (Math reliant question)

Tags: mathematics

So I've been checking some games to get ideas for my own. Some designs I've reviewed rely on a few variables like:

- Current level
- Current exp
- Exp to next level

I aim for a simplistic design where there is only an exp variable.

Example:

> Level 1
>
> Current exp: 0
>
> Exp to next level: 100
>
> Level 2
>
> Current exp: 100
>
> Exp to next level: 200
>
> Level 3
>
> Current exp: 200
>
> Exp to next level: 400
>
> Level 4
>
> Current exp: 400
>
> Exp to next level: 800

Every level, the exp required for next level doubles.

That's okay. Since I use only an exp variable, I need two formulas:

1. Formula to calculate the current level
2. Formula to calculate the exp required for next level

My progress so far:

> Level = floor((exp + 100)/100)

This works for 0 exp (level 1) because floor(0 + 100)/100 equals 1, with 50 exp works fine too:

50 + 100 = 150
150/100
1.5
flooring 1,5 gets us to 1

If we hit 100 exp, we should be now at level 2.

floor((100+100)/100) = 2

Let's see level three.

floor((100 + **200**)/100) = 3

Since level 3 is at least **200** exp, this thing keeps working.

Level 4 begins with 400 exp.

Let's see what happens if we have 399 exp.
399 + 100
499/100 = 4.9
floor(4.9)
4

No way. 399 should still be level 3.

So let's take into account the doubling factor.

Level = floor((exp + 100)/100)**/2**

399 + 100 = 499... / 100 = 4.99 .. floored -> 4 / 2 = 2

Level 2? No way , it should be level 3

Another try:

Level = floor((exp/100))

floor(399/100) = 3
floor(400/100) = 4

But if we apply the formula to level 2(starting at 100, ending at 200 which would be level 3)

floor(100/100) = 1

I can't seem to achieve this on my own. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please visit [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) page to merge your accounts, you'll be able to comment and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because your EXP amount is doubling, simple division isn't enough. You have exponents, and you need to use their inverse, the logarithm function.

## Calculating the Amount Needed for the Next Level

If you're on level `n`, the amount of experience points to get to level `n+1` is `100 * 2^(n-1)`. (eg. if `n` is 1, you get 100; if `n` is 3, you get 400.)

If the notation isn't familiar to you, `2^(n-1)` means "two to the power of (n minus one)." And of course, `2^0 = 1`.

## Calculating the Current Level

If you invert the formula and solve for `n` instead of solving for `exp`, you get:

```
1 + log(exp/100) / log(2)

or

        log(exp/100)
   1 +  ------------
        log(2)
```

`exp` is the current number of experience points; `log` is the logarithm function.

If I plug in in 376 for `exp`, I get a value of `2.91`. Rounding down, the player is on level 2, which is correct.